# TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined $routeparams error

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm having trouble with fetching the Api on my RouteParam page, I'd like the page to open up a new API with the info on given drivers, however when I open the route, the error says that the "id" is undefined. I'd like to know how I could fix my code in order to display such info with 2 different API's.

I tried googling a ton of answers and changing my ID however nothing seems to work, I believe it has something to do with either the ID being wrong or the 2 functions working asynchronously however I cannot pinpoint the exact issue. The service is working with the other two of my API's but not this one.

Routing

```
module app { 
    const app = angular.module("app",['ngRoute']);
    app.config(routeConfig);
    require('./controllers/service');
    require('./controllers/drivers');
    require('./controllers/teams');
    require('./controllers/driver')
    require('route-params')

    // require('angular-route');
    routeConfig.$inject = ["$routeProvider"];

    function routeConfig($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/drivers', {
                templateUrl: './src/pages/drivers.html',
                controller: 'DriversListCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })
            .when('/drivers/:driverId', {
                templateUrl: './src/pages/driverDetails.html',
                controller: 'DriverDetailsCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })
            .when('/teams', {
                templateUrl: './src/pages/teams.html',
                controller: 'TeamListCtrl',
                controllerAs:'vm'
            })  
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo:'/drivers'
            })
    }
}
```

service

```
module app.service {

    export interface IDataAccessService {
        getDriversApi():ng.IPromise<IDriver>;
        getDriverDetailsApi(id:number):ng.IPromise<IDriverDetails>
        getDriverRacesApi(id:number):ng.IPromise<IDriverRaces>
    }

    export class DataAccessService implements IDataAccessService {

        static $inject = ['$http'];
        constructor(private $http: ng.IHttpService,public id:any) {

        }
        getDriversApi():ng.IPromise<IDriver>{
            return this.$http.get('https://ergast.com/api/f1/2013/driverStandings.json')
            .then((response:ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<IDriver>):IDriver=>{ 
                return response.data;
            })
        }
        getDriverDetailsApi(id:any):ng.IPromise<IDriverDetails>{
            return this.$http.get('http://ergast.com/api/f1/2013/drivers/'+ id +'/driverStandings.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
            .then((response:ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<IDriverDetails>):IDriverDetails=>{ 
                return response.data;
            })
        }
        getDriverRacesApi(id:any):ng.IPromise<IDriverRaces>{
            return this.$http.get('http://ergast.com/api/f1/2013/drivers/'+ id +'/results.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
            .then((response:ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<IDriverRaces>):IDriverRaces=>{ 
                return response.data;
```

controller

```
    export class DriverDetailsCtrl implements IDriverDetails {


        static $inject = ["dataAccessService", "$routeParams"];
        constructor(
            private dataAccessService: app.service.DataAccessService,
            public driverDet,
            public nameFilter,
            public driverId,
            public races,
            public $routeParams // 
        ) {
            this.driverId = $routeParams.id;


            this.dataAccessService.getDriverDetailsApi(this.driverId)
                .then((data: any): void => {
                    this.driverDet = data.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists[0].DriverStandings[0];
                    console.log(driverDet)
                    return this.driverDet;
                });
            this.dataAccessService.getDriverRacesApi(this.driverId)
                .then((data: any): void => {
                    this.races = data.MRData.RaceTable.Races;
                    console.log(races)
                    return this.races;
                });
        }
```

Comment: Try  this.driverId = $routeParams.driverId; instead this.driverId = $routeParams.id;

Comment: I tried but now I get the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'driverId' of undefined"

Comment: I was having the same issue with angularJS 1.7.  Turns out that it was the use of $inject.  For some reason it doesn't appear to work for $routeParams.

Comment: @BShaps so how did you fix it?

Comment: @bobthehackerman I used the `angular.module('app').controller('controllerName', ['$routeParams', controllerFn])` syntax.  Every other dependency I use `$inject` but for some reason $routeParams came up as undefined.